# Running a Linux command from R on Windows Server 2012

Tags: r, linux, bash, windows-server-2012-r2

I have an R installation on Windows Server 2012, and I am trying to execute a command on a Linux Server - something like

`bash echo \"samplecommand?filename=testfile.zip\" | nc -vv -w 2 testserver portnumber`

As far as I understand, WSL exists from Windows 10 which makes it easy to execute linux bash scripts. 
Is it possible to do this in R from Windows Server 2012 R2, or any other way to achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think my question might have been worded incorrectly. The actual app I wanted to execute was netcat (nc), so all I needed to do was install netcat for windows and then execute

```
input = "cd C:\\folderwherenetcatisinstalled
echo samplecommand?filename=testfilename| nc -w2 servername portnumber"
system("cmd.exe", input = input)
```